# Why npm watch doesn't do anything

Tags: php, reactjs, npm

Hello i am working on a project in php laravel homestead and inside of it there is a react part . I was using `npm run watch` until yesterday and it was working perfectly. But i dont know why npm run watch doesnt do anything its working as usual also noticing the changes but when i open the project on web browser there was no change. I did change class even comment the whole class but nothing has changed on web browser. I deleted

> node_modules

folder and reinstall, install npm again. I thought it might be **Intellij's** problem so `Invalidate caches and restart` but still no improvement. 
this is my console:

```
 DONE  Compiled successfully in 3361ms                                                                                                                                                                10:29:30

       Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
  /js/app.js  8.89 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  /js/app
/css/app.css  0 bytes       0  [emitted]         /js/app
 + 2 hidden assets
```

this webpack.mix.js:

```
mix.react('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Please, how can i fix it what would be the problem ? There is no error. How can i delete npm watch caches ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found the problem its about Web browser(Chrome) i delete all cookies and history and its updated. Now i am using Firefox and there is no problem.

Comment: I also clear the history. But the problem is I keep doing this 100x a day. I even installed BrowserSync plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `sudo npm run watch` sometimes does not have the right permissions to run services

Comment: i was using from intellij not from Vagrant npm does not working corretly in ubuntu.